# aw.js grid delete and update issue

Tags: javascript, gridview

I'm using `aw.js` grid view.  I need to update and delete rows in the grid.  But after deleting a row I cannot `add another row`. The grid index shows `NaN`. If anyone is familiar with this grid view please advice me